# Bootstrap 4: Carousel Fade Transition Not Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-4

The below code worked perfectly fine for me using Bootstrap version 3. However, since upgrading to Bootstrap 4 Beta2 the fade transition does not work. It just jumps to the next image rather than a smooth transition:

HTML

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active"><img src="images/a.jpg" alt="First slide image" class="center-block">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide Heading</h3>
          <p>First slide Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/b.jpg" alt="Second slide image" class="center-block">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide Heading</h3>
          <p>Second slide Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/c.jpg" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide Heading</h3>
          <p>Third slide Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel.fade {
     opacity: 1;
}
.carousel.fade .item {
    transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0; /* hide all slides */
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.carousel.fade .item:first-child {
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1; /* show first slide */
    position: relative;
}
.carousel.fade .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000
    });
});
```

Looking around and it seems that there has been a few issues with the recent bootstrap upgrade, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you have already noticed, quite a lot of things have been changed in Bootstrap 4. Let me walk you through the approach I took with the solution below.

- `.fade` was renamed to `.carousel-fade` not to interfere with the default Bootstrap `.fade` class.
- `.item` was renamed to `.carousel-item`, since that is the name in Bootsrap 4 for carousel items.
- As the positioning of the slides is absolute now because of the fading effect, I added `.embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9` classes to `.carousel-inner` and also `.embed-responsive-item` to `.carousel-item` to preserve the height of the slide container and also to take care of the positioning of the slide items. (In case you want to use images with other aspect ratios, you should change the `.embed-responsive-16by9` class. Defaults are listed [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/#aspect-ratios).)

So this would be my approach:

```css
.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-fade" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item active">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900/483D8B/ffffff?text=Slide%201" alt="First slide image" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide Heading</h3>
          <p>First slide Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900/9400D3/ffffff?text=Slide%202" alt="Second slide image" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide Heading</h3>
          <p>Second slide Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900/FF1493/ffffff?text=Slide%203" alt="Third slide image" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide Heading</h3>
          <p>Third slide Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Two more notes:

- You can also set the change interval via the `data-interval` attribute of the `.carousel`.
- The markup of the carousel controls have also been changed in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this worked a treat.  To be honest I'm relatively new to bootstrap so this is the first upgrade I've seen.  I'm shocked that their upgrades can break simple functions but I can see why they've implemented. thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! FYI: major version changes more than often break things, but that's how the tool evolves.

Comment: I think the 'embed-responsive' class is making the carousel a fixed height and is not responsive like my image.  The carousel headings and indicators are fixed in position but my image is responsive.

Comment: `.embed-responsive-16by9` is fixing the aspect ratio of `.carousel-inner`, not just the height itself. (Other default [aspect ratio classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/#aspect-ratios) are available as well.) As `.carousel-item`s have to be absolute positioned because of the transition effect, the wrapper (`.carousel-inner`) has to have a set height. But this height is set by padding in %, not the via the height attribute, thus it is responsive.

Comment: You mean, your images are with other aspect ratios? FYI: `16by9` is for images like 1600x900, 1280x720 etc…, and similarly `4by3` is for e.g. 1200x900 sized images. If your image has other aspect ratio than the available presets, you could create your own `.embed-responsive-XbyY` class. You could use the [original scss definitions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/utilities/_embed.scss) as a sample.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll have a go at that, worst case I only have to alter my image's slightly.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.